# Please advice Canadian hosting

Tags: web-hosting

please advice good Canadian hosting could offer different c-class IPs

Thanks a lot,
J

Comment: Localised questions aren't appropriate for SO.

Comment: Belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: a) there's no such thing as a 'c' class IP and there hasn't been for over 10 years, b) as this is a hosting thing, it should be on serverfault.com, c) as it's asking for specific localised assistance, it would be closed as 'too localised' over there as well.